# What is the equivalent Eloquent ORM usage of Laravel PHP in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, laravel-4, eloquent

How do you use ASP.NET MVC's Entity ORM framework like Laravel's Eloquent ORM?
For example, with Eloquent in Laravel, you can insert a new record like this:

```
// instantiate the User model
$user = User();

// set values
$user->email() = 'zanbek@email.com';
$user->name() = 'Zan Bek';
$user->age = '20';

// save
$user->save();
```

Here, you can see that its fun to make database queries with Laravel's Eloquent ORM. You don't even need to put much in the User model like the database's columns.

My question is, how do make database queries in ASP.NET MVC's Entity ORM like Laravel's Eloquent shown in the example code above?

Comment: Have you tried to use EF yet?

Comment: I tried but the tutorials from http:www.asp.net/mvc teaches only the automated database CRUD functionalities (bindings) such as the Code-First and Database-First. I can't utilise those features because I have an existing database that isn't very relational (has bad structures).

Comment: can you please add your recommendation for ASP.net? It seems that there are many options and each have many advantages and disadvantages.

Answer (score 1):

Using EntityFramework, you could simply create a user through:

```
var user = new User();
user.email = "zanbek@email.com";
user.name = "Zan Bek";
user.age = 20;

context.Users.Add(user);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use subsonic

Sample No. 1 - Fetching all of the products that have a ListPrice greater than $50.00, a Class value of L, and is the Color Yellow.

```
Query qry = Product.CreateQuery().WHERE("ListPrice > 50.00")
        .AND("Class = L").AND("Color = Yellow");
 IDataReader rdr = qry.ExecuteReader();

while (rdr.Read()) {
    Console.WriteLine(rdr[Product.Columns.Name].ToString());
  }
```

Sample No. 2 - Adding a new product.

```
Currency c = new Currency();
c.CurrencyCode = "CPD";
c.Name = "Code Project Dollar";
c.Save("Some_UserName");
```

Referene

[Subsonic](https://github.com/subsonic/SubSonic-3.0)

[Codeproject link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21244/Creating-a-DAL-with-SubSonic)